# Binding child virtual class data to view in ASP.NET MVC for Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So I'm having a bit of problem with biding class data to an ASP.NET MVC view (I'm new to ASP.NET MVC btw).

Normally it would not be a problem for I could get the data later or do something, but the problem is in my controller class that validates the data return false and breaks the function.

I could remove the validator but unfortunately its required, and I don't have time to rewrite it.

I digress... My question is how to bind that data on the view and send it properly to the controller?

[image: The problem as seen in debugger]

This is the model class:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }

    public virtual Catalog Catalog { get; set; } //<-- This is where my Problem is
}
```

This is the controller method for model-view binding:

```
 public ActionResult Update(int? id)
    {
        if(id != null)
        {
            var productManager = new ProductManager();
            var model = productManager.GetProductByID(id.Value);
            return View(model);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is the view:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { @Value = Model.Id })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code, new { @Value = Model.Code })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { @Value = Model.Description })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CatalogId, new { @Value = Model.CatalogId })</td>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Catalog, new { @Value = Model.Catalog })</td>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Catalog.Id, new { @Value = Model.Catalog.Id })</td>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Catalog.Code, new { @Value = Model.Catalog.Code })</td>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Catalog.Description, new { @Value = Model.Catalog.Description })</td>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Catalog.Product, new { @Value = Model.Catalog.Product })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Update</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

This is the controller method for updating the product:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Update")]
public ActionResult Update(EURIS.Entities.Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) //<-- Product.Catalog is null and IsValid return false
    {  
        ProductManager productManager = new ProductManager();
        productManager.UpdateProduct(product);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the properties of the catalog (and probably also the catalog id) into your view, probably as a hidden field to ensure that it makes the round trip back to the server and is populated in your model when the controller executes on the Update.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CatalogId, new { @Value = ViewBag.CatalogId }
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Catalog.Id, new { @Value = ViewBag.Catalog.Code }
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Catalog.Title, new { @Value = ViewBag.Catalog.Title }
```

The Catalog property is a complex object and MVC does not that a way to render it into the view by itself. In situations like that, I put the needed properties into hidden fields so that they are available in the edit/update actions of the controller.

Comment: Hi thank you. But the problem persists. When it goes back to the server the catalog property is still null.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need any ViewBag, so change your action:

```
var model=context.Set<Product>().FirstOrDefault(i=> I.Id==id);
return View(model);
```

since you dont need any ViewBag, remove all ViewBag code from view. For example it should be

```
@if (Model != null)
{
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)</td>
.....
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code)</td>

....and so on
```

Catalog is a virual or navigation property. You don't need  the whole Catalog instance to save Product,  you can use only hidden CatalogId:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CatalogId);
```

UPDATE

Catalog inctance can be included

```
var model=context.Set<Product>().Include(c=> c.Catalog).FirstOrDefault(i=> I.Id==id);
```

but I can't see any use of Catalog in your view. Pls update your post if you need to make some Catalog changes in the same time.

Comment: Hi thank you. A great suggestion, I did edit the code. But this unfortunately doesn't solve my problem. The catalog complex property is still null on update.

Comment: What do you need a catalog property for? Do you need to make some changes?  I can fill it but I don't see any use.

Comment: You are rigth, after a good night sleep I saw i made a great mistake in the very beginning of the project. In a nutshell... I am trying to make a many to many relation between catalog and product. I needed to rewrite everything from scratch. Thank you for your time anyway :)